# pyspark delta table schema evolution nullable

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

I am using the schema evolution in delta table and the code is written in databricks notebook.

```
df_read = spark.read.schema(schema)
        .format(file_format)
        .option("inferSchema", "false")
        .option("mergeSchema", "true")
        .load(source_folders)
```

But I still got the error below. Is it correct to define the schema and enable the mergeSchema at the same time?

```
AnalysisException: The specified schema does not match the existing schema at path.
== Specified ==

    root
    -- A: string (nullable = false)
    -- B: string (nullable = true)
    -- C: long (nullable = true)
    
== Existing ==
    root
    -- A: string (nullable = true)
    -- B: string (nullable = true)
    -- C: long (nullable = true)

== Differences==
- Field A is non-nullable in specified schema but nullable in existing schema.

If your intention is to keep the existing schema, you can omit the
schema from the create table command. Otherwise please ensure that
the schema matches.
```

Comment: Why did you do to "using the schema evolution in delta table"? How does the `source_folders` directory look like?